# Curl the webpage hosted on the same EC2 instance not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I have the web application hosted on EC2 instance and created the DNS for it. The web page works fine when I hit the URL in browser. However, when I `curl` the URL from EC2 instance, there is no response or rather getting connection error.

```
curl: (7) Failed connect to dnsurl.com:80; Operation now in progress
```

Also, in my web application, I am calling a servlet inside another servlet using [Apache Post method](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/methods/PostMethod.html). This is not working as well. The same code works fine on non-EC2 servers.

**Not working:-**

```
curl dnsurl.com
curl elburl.com
```

**Working:-**

Curl to other http urls are working fine from EC2 instance

```
curl http://www.w3schools.com/Tags/ref_urlencode.asp
```

Comment: Please provide the details of the security group assigned to your EC2 instance.  Does the web app require connections via https?

Comment: No, it doesn't require https.

Comment: When you say the web page "...works fine when I hit the URL in browser."  Is this from the internet? or from the instance? from another instance in same subnet? VPC?

Answer (score 3):

Your URLs are resolved to the public IP addresses. So the request goes outside your EC2 instance. For that to work you need the following:

1. Your security group should allow outbound traffic on port 80.
2. Your network ACL should allow outbound traffic on port 80.

Answer (score 0):

Opening the **ALB (Application Load Balancer)** to allow inbound traffic from the EC2 instance on port 80 has resolved the issue.